# PHP Google Analytics API - Simple query

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I tried show simple query (total views) from my Google Analytics account on common web page.
I put such code:

```
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';       
//session_start();      
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("###");  
    $client->setClientId('####.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('###');
    $client->setRedirectUri('###');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));



  //first authentication

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

//first call

$ids = 'ga:###'; //your id
$startDate = '2013-12-25';
$endDate = '2014-01-08';
$metrics = 'ga:transactions';

$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:campaign',
    'max-results' => '10'
);

$results = $service->data_ga->get($ids, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $optParams);

//Dump results
echo "<h3>Results Of Call:</h3>";

echo "dump of results";
var_dump($results);

echo "results['totalsForAllResults']";
var_dump($results['totalsForAllResults']);

echo "results['rows']";
foreach ($results['rows'] as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
}

//second call

$results = $service->data_ga;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

In private data I wrote ###. I don't know why it doesn't work.
The output is:
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in path.php on line 19

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in path.php on line 39

Could anyone help me?

Comment: `$key_file_location?` is not defined, where you define it?

Comment: What's that? Extra file with some secret data as in variable $client?

Comment: Also, wouldn't you need to actually create an Analytics Service Object before you call it? I don't see you declaring/instantiate $service before calling methods from it.

Comment: Stil I'can't find key_file_location, I have sth like file called "###################.p12", nothing similar to ###########################-privatekey.p12, how to find right file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, private key location was found:)
But still has communicate on page:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /###/index.php:1) in /home/users/marcwars/public_html/wpress/index.php on line 3

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /###/index.php:1) in /home/users/marcwars/public_html/wpress/index.php on line 3

Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /###/Google/Service/Analytics.php on line 32
```

Have anyone similar problems?